# _Callback<>, _toByteData() and _futurize() not defined

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having this issue in Flutter:

`Error: The method '_futurize' isn't defined for the class '_MainPage'.`

`Error: The method '_toByteData' isn't defined for the class '_MainPage'`

`Error: '_Callback' isn't a type.`

This is in the function mentioned at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Image/toByteData.html, which is used to obtain the binary value of an image.

Actual code is:

```
Future<ByteData?> toByteData({ImageByteFormat format = ImageByteFormat.rawRgba}) {
  return _futurize((_Callback<ByteData> callback) {
    return _toByteData(format.index, (Uint8List? encoded) {
      callback(encoded!.buffer.asByteData());
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've cited represents *how* the code has been implemented.

For that reason, the `_futurize` and `_toByteData` methods are `private` to the `Image` class and can't be accessed from the outside, hence the errors.

If you'd like to use the `toByteData()` function, you could simply use a code like the following:

```
ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData();
```

Comment: God! I messed it up. You're right, thank you.